# java parsing xml and retriving child data from complex xml

Tags: java, xml, file, parsing, dom

I am trying parse an xml file by using below java code. The problem is while it is reading data from inner I can retrive data data from every where but if there are multi items under one package which means, while it does not retrive all child under parent would you please help?

```
 import java.io.File;
 import org.w3c.dom.*;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile{

public static void ReadXmlandParce(String filename){
try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(filename));

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
        System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
             doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


        NodeList Messagend = doc.getElementsByTagName("IMessage");

        for(int s=0; s<Messagend.getLength() ; s++){


            Node MessageItemNode = Messagend.item(s);
            if(MessageItemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                Element MessageElement = (Element)MessageItemNode;

                //-------
                NodeList MessageNamend =  MessageElement.getElementsByTagName("IMessageName");
                Element MessageNameElement = (Element)MessageNamend.item(0);

                NodeList textMessageName = MessageNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("MessageName : " + 
                       ((Node)textMessageName.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //-------
                NodeList MessageDatend = MessageElement.getElementsByTagName("IMessageDate");
                Element MessageDateElement = (Element)MessageDatend.item(0);

                NodeList textMessageDate = MessageDateElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("MessageDate : " + 
                       ((Node)textMessageDate.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //----
                NodeList ServiceOrderednd = MessageElement.getElementsByTagName("IServiceOrderedType");
                Element ServiceOrderedElement = (Element)ServiceOrderednd.item(0);

                NodeList textServiceOrdered = ServiceOrderedElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("ServiceOrdered : " + 
                       ((Node)textServiceOrdered.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //------     

                NodeList ServiceTypend = MessageElement.getElementsByTagName("IServiceType");
                Element ServiceTypeElement = (Element)ServiceTypend.item(0);

                NodeList textServiceType = ServiceTypeElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("ServiceType : " + 
                       ((Node)textServiceType.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //------  

                NodeList SpecialInstructionsnd = MessageElement.getElementsByTagName("Instructions");
                Element SpecialInstructionsElement = (Element)SpecialInstructionsnd.item(0);

                NodeList textSpecialInstructions = SpecialInstructionsElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("SpecialInstructions : " + 
                       ((Node)textSpecialInstructions.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //------  

                NodeList CompanyNamend = MessageElement.getElementsByTagName("CompanyName");
                Element CompanyNameElement = (Element)CompanyNamend.item(0);

                NodeList textCompanyName = CompanyNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("CompanyName : " + 
                       ((Node)textCompanyName.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //------  



            }//end of if clause


        }//end of for loop with s var


        ///////////////////////////////////
        NodeList Consigneend = doc.getElementsByTagName("UConsignee");


        for(int j=0; j<Consigneend.getLength() ; j++){


            Node ConsigneeItemNode = Consigneend.item(j);
            if(ConsigneeItemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                Element ConsigneeElement = (Element)ConsigneeItemNode;

                //-------
                NodeList CompanyCodend = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("UCompanyCode");
                Element  CompanyCodeElement = (Element)CompanyCodend.item(0);

                NodeList textCompanyCode = CompanyCodeElement.getChildNodes();

                try{
                System.out.println("UCompanyCode : " +((Node)textCompanyCode.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("UCompanyCode : empty");

                    }

                //-------
                NodeList CompanyNamend = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("UCompanyName");
                Element  CompanyNameElement = (Element)CompanyNamend.item(0);

                NodeList textCompanyName = CompanyNameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("CompanyName : " + 
                       ((Node)textCompanyName.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //----
                NodeList TaxNond = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("UTaxNo");
                Element TaxNoElement = (Element)TaxNond.item(0);

                NodeList textTaxNo= TaxNoElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("TaxNo : " + 
                       ((Node)textTaxNo.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                //------                     

                NodeList Street1nd = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("Street1");
                Element  Street1Element = (Element)Street1nd.item(0);

                NodeList textStreet1 = Street1Element.getChildNodes();
                try{
                System.out.println("Street1 : " + 
                       ((Node)textStreet1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("Street1 : empty");
                    }
                //----                    
                NodeList Street2nd = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("Street2");
                Element  Street2Element = (Element)Street2nd.item(0);

                NodeList textStreet2 = Street2Element.getChildNodes();
                try{
                System.out.println("Street2 : " + 
                       ((Node)textStreet2.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("Street2 : empty");
                    }
                //----                    
                NodeList PostalCodend = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("PostalCode");
                Element  PostalCodeElement = (Element)PostalCodend.item(0);

                NodeList textPostalCode = PostalCodeElement.getChildNodes();
                try{
                System.out.println("PostalCode : " + 
                       ((Node)textPostalCode.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("PostalCode : empty");
                    }
                //----
                NodeList CityNamend = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("CityName");
                Element  CityNameElement = (Element)CityNamend.item(0);

                NodeList textCityName = CityNameElement.getChildNodes();
                try{
                System.out.println("CityName : " + 
                       ((Node)textCityName.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("CityName : empty");
                    }
                //----

                NodeList Countrynd = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("Country");
                Element  CountryElement = (Element)Countrynd.item(0);

                NodeList textCountry = CountryElement.getChildNodes();
                try{
                System.out.println("Country : " + 
                       ((Node)textCountry.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("Country : Bos");
                    }
                //----

                NodeList TaxRegNond = ConsigneeElement.getElementsByTagName("TaxRegNo");
                Element  TaxRegNoElement = (Element)TaxRegNond.item(0);

                NodeList textTaxRegNo = TaxRegNoElement.getChildNodes();
                try{
                System.out.println("TaxRegNo : " + 
                       ((Node)textTaxRegNo.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                }
                catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                    System.out.println ("TaxRegNo : empty");
                    }
                //----
                System.out.println ("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.println ("Begin of Package");
                System.out.println ("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                NodeList Packagend = doc.getElementsByTagName("CPackage");


                for(int k=0; k<Packagend.getLength() ; k++){

                    Node PackageItemNode = Packagend.item(k);
                    if(PackageItemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                        Element PackageElement = (Element)PackageItemNode;

                        //-------
                        NodeList PackageTypend = PackageElement.getElementsByTagName("CPackageType");
                        Element  PackageTypeElement = (Element)PackageTypend.item(0);
                        NodeList textPackageType = PackageTypeElement.getChildNodes();
                        try{
                        System.out.println("PackageType : " + 
                                ((Node)textPackageType.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                            System.out.println ("PackageType : empty");
                            }
                        //-------
                        NodeList GrossWeightnd = PackageElement.getElementsByTagName("CGrossWeight");
                        Element  GrossWeightElement = (Element)GrossWeightnd.item(0);
                        NodeList textGrossWeight = GrossWeightElement.getChildNodes();
                        try{
                        System.out.println("GrossWeight : " + 
                                ((Node)textGrossWeight.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                            System.out.println ("GrossWeight : empty");
                            }
                        //-------
                        NodeList Barcodend = PackageElement.getElementsByTagName("CBarcode");
                        Element  BarcodeElement = (Element)Barcodend.item(0);
                        NodeList textBarcode = BarcodeElement.getChildNodes();
                        try{
                        System.out.println("Barcode : " + 
                                ((Node)textBarcode.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                            System.out.println ("Barcode : empty");

                            }
                        //-------

                        System.out.println ("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                        System.out.println ("Begin of Item");
                        System.out.println ("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                        NodeList Itemnd = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");


                        for(int p=0; p<Itemnd.getLength() ; p++){


                            Node ItemNode = Itemnd.item(p);
                            if(ItemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                                Element ItemElement = (Element)ItemNode;

                        NodeList ItemCodend = ItemElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemCode");
                        Element  ItemCodeElement = (Element)ItemCodend.item(0);
                        NodeList textItemCode = ItemCodeElement.getChildNodes();
                        try{
                        System.out.println("ItemCode : " + 
                                ((Node)textItemCode.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                            System.out.println ("ItemCode : empty");
                            }
                        //-------
                        NodeList Quantitynd = ItemElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemQuantity");
                        Element  QuantityElement = (Element)Quantitynd.item(0);
                        NodeList textQuantity = QuantityElement.getChildNodes();
                        try{
                        System.out.println("Quantity : " + 
                                ((Node)textQuantity.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException err ) {
                            System.out.println ("Quantity : empty");
                            }
                        //-------

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }


            }//end of if clause


        }
        ///////////////////////////////////


    }catch (SAXParseException err) {
    System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " 
         + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
    System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());

    }catch (SAXException e) {
    Exception x = e.getException ();
    ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();

    }catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace ();
    }
    //System.exit (0);

}

}
```

> Please find xml as below

```
<IMessage>
<IMessageName>IM1234</IMessageName>
<IMessageDate>20140328</IMessageDate>
<IServiceOrderedType>Normal</IServiceOrderedType>
<IServiceType>AIR</IServiceType>
<Instructions>OP123456</Instructions>
<CompanyName>Test</CompanyName>
<UConsignee>
<UCompanyCode></UCompanyCode>
<UTaxNo>T1231132123</UTaxNo>
<Street1>test132132</Street1>
<Street2>Streeet1</Street2>
<PostalCode>121212</PostalCode>
<CityName>London</CityName>
<Country>UK</Country>
<TaxRegNo>121313</TaxRegNo>
<CPackage>
<CPackageType>BIG</CPackageType>
<CGrossWeight>12</CGrossWeight>
<CBarcode>54353454353</CBarcode>
<Item>
<ItemCode>IT122111</ItemCode>
<ItemQuantity>50</ItemQuantity>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemCode>IT122851</ItemCode>
<ItemQuantity>10</ItemQuantity>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemCode>IT122151</ItemCode>
<ItemQuantity>18</ItemQuantity>
</Item>
</CPackage>
<CPackage>
<CPackageType>MEDIUM</CPackageType>
<CGrossWeight>14</CGrossWeight>
<CBarcode>54353454354</CBarcode>
<Item>
<ItemCode>IT18581</ItemCode>
<ItemQuantity>100</ItemQuantity>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemCode>IT98561</ItemCode>
<ItemQuantity>60</ItemQuantity>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemCode>IT68961</ItemCode>
<ItemQuantity>12</ItemQuantity>
</Item>
</CPackage>
</UConsignee>
</IMessage>
```

Comment: I cannot understand out what you are asking here.  (And you seem to have mangled your code somehow.  What are all of those spurious `>` characters about?)

Comment: Could you expose that XML so that it will be easier..

Comment: The xml is such below

Comment: I think @ashokramsce means ... "show us the XML please".

Comment: @zorox - Below what?  I can't see any XML in the question.  Put it into the question.

Comment: @zorox - put it into the question.  And please format it.

Comment: @zorox use the "edit" link.

Comment: I don't understand your question either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer that should be continue to iteration by nested NodeList methood as below code

> ```
>   NodeList PackageRootNodeList = Messagend .getElementsByTagName("CPackage");
>
>    for(int n=0; n<PackageRootNodeList .getLength() ; n++){
>
>
>        Node PackageNode = PackageRootNodeList .item(s);
>        Element PackageRootElement = (Element)PackageNode ;
>
>            //-------
> ```
>
> NodeList PackageBarcodeNodeList = PackageRootElement .getElementsByTagName("CBarcode");
>     Element  PackageBarcodeElement = (Element)PackageBarcodeNodeList .item(0);
>
> ```
>    NodeList textCBarcode = PackageBarcodeElement .getChildNodes();
>            System.out.println("CBarcode: " + 
>                   ((Node)textCBarcode.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
>
>  /////
>  /////   You will continue as the same methood in order to make deep iteration
>  /////
>            }
> ```